# How can I bcrypt a password during Yii2 Migrations?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have a question. I have a migration file, that batchInserts an admin user and a normal user into a database. Now I have the files ready and they work fine. However, the password used to have a md5 hash during insert in Yii1.1 something like this:
`'password'=>md5('admin')`

My question is, can I do something similar in Yii2 with bcrypt? Where I encrypt the password during creation? I use `batchInsert('users', ['column1', 'column2' ...], ['Jon', 'Doe' ...], ['Jane', 'Doe'...])`

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to hash password in Yii2 is using [`yii\base\Security::generatePasswordHash()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-security#generatePasswordHash()-detail).
This method uses [`password_hash()`](https://www.php.net/password_hash) function with `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` constant as algorithm. I think currently that constant still refers to bcrypt algorithm. But it's meant to be future-proof. When PHP moves to another algorithm you wouldn't need to change your code. If the `password_hash()` function is not available the `generatePasswordHash()` methods fallback to `crypt()` function.

In migration you can use application components in same way you would use them anywhere else. For example:

```php
$this->batchInsert(
    'users',
    ['first_name', 'last_name', 'password', ...],
    [
        ['John', 'Doe', Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash('mySecretPassword'), ...],
        ['Jane', 'Doe', Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash('anotherPassword'), ...],
    ]
);
```

Or if you prefer dependency injection approach:

```
use yii\base\Security;
use yii\db\Migration;

class WhateverMigrationName extends Migration
{
    private Security $security;
    public function __construct(Security $security, $config = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($config);
        $this->security = $security;
    }

    public function safeUp()
    {
        // ...
        $this->batchInsert(
            'users',
            ['first_name', 'last_name', 'password', ...],
            [
                ['John', 'Doe', $this->security->generatePasswordHash('mySecretPassword'), ...],
                ['Jane', 'Doe', $this->security->generatePasswordHash('anotherPassword'), ...],
            ]
        );
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

To verify password against hash created by `generatePasswordHash()` you can call [`yii\base\Security::validatePassword()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-security#validatePassword()-detail) method in same way. For example:

```php
Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $storedHash);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, man. You really helping me out here. I will try it as soon as I can. Might I ask another question?

Comment: If your question is related to my answer than ask it here in comments. If it's about something else then please open a new question. I will answer it there if I can or someone else might answer it.